# How can I get the class of a hidden element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

This must be possible. I see all sorts of answers for how to get the class of a `div` etc. Here is what I am doing:

```
    var $outMap = $('img').not(':hidden');

    alert($outMap.attr("class"));
```

It comes up `undefined`. I know that $outMap is valid because I can use it to make said hidden element `.fadeOut` but I want to retrieve the class of this element. I came up with the above code after trying:

```
alert($('img').not(':hidden').attr("class"));
```

I am sure they are doing the same thing I just don't know what else to try.

Comment: `.not(':hidden')` will select visible elements. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your question title says 'get the class of a hidden element' but the code you show is `$('img').not(':hidden')`. These seem contradictory. Are you trying to find the visible images (i.e. `not(:hidden)`) or the hidden ones (i.e. `$('img:hidden')`)?

Comment: @Scimonster whatever the case, I need to get the class of that element. Whether it is `.not(':visibile')` or `.not(':hidden')` makes no difference. Sometimes coming up with how to phrase question is hard.

Comment: @neuronaut I am not trying to find the visible images or invisible images. I am trying to find the class of them, whether it is `.not(':visible')` or `.not(':hidden')`.

Comment: @Christine268 I understand that finding the images themselves isn't the end goal, but until you find them you can't get their class. I was simply trying to get clarification on which kind of images you wanted the class of since the title and code samples seemed to contradict each other.

Comment: @neuronaut I am finding the images I want to get the class of. * know that $outMap is valid because I can use it to make said hidden element .fadeOut* is what I said in OP. My problem was then using that to find the **class** of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that while jQuery's selectors will return any number of elements found, the `attr` function only operates when there's a single element.

To illustrate let's say you have a page with 5 images (doesn't matter if they are hidden or visible). If you do `$('img')` then you'll get 5 results, and calling `.attr('class')` then returns `undefined`.

However, if you select a single image, say by selecting it by its `id` attribute, then `.attr('class')` will work: `$('#some-image-id').attr('class')` will give you the class.

If you need to get the class for each of several images you'll need to iterate, perhaps using jQuery's `.each` function:

```
$('img:hidden').each(function(n, image) {
    alert($(image).attr('class'));
});
```

(Note that the `n` paramter is just a number that is incremented for each time through the loop.)

Comment: Ok so it was just because I had more than one image being captured. Simple enough.